# How to get readable and useful call/error stacks in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

When developping Angular 4 applications, I often get unreadable call stacks where only generated files are mentionned. Something like that:

```
ERROR TypeError: _co.archive is undefined
Trace de la pile :
View_UploadScriptFormComponent_0/<@ng:///AppModule/UploadScriptFormComponent.ngfactory.js:346:9
debugUpdateRenderer@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:67835:12
checkAndUpdateView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66982:5
callViewAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:67342:21
execComponentViewsAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:67274:13
checkAndUpdateView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66983:5
callViewAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:67342:21
execComponentViewsAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:67274:13
checkAndUpdateView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66983:5
callViewAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:67342:21
execEmbeddedViewsAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:67300:17
checkAndUpdateView@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66978:5
callViewAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:67342:21
execComponentViewsAction@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:67274:13
[...]
../../../../rxjs/Subject.js/Subject.prototype.next@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:10145:17
../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js/</EventEmitter.prototype.emit@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:58343:54
checkStable@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:58577:13
onHasTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:58625:21
../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/</</ZoneDelegate.prototype.hasTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2962:21
../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/</</ZoneDelegate.prototype._updateTaskCount@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2982:17
../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/</</Zone.prototype._updateTaskCount@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2806:17
../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/</</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:2726:25
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js:3119:25
```

In this particular error, I have zero variables called `_co`, and a property archive used in multiple location. `UploadScriptFormComponent.ngfactory.js` is generated and not part of my source files.

Of course I could try to remove code until I can identify where the error comes from, but this is a stupid and time-consuming approach.

Is there a way to get actual, useful error data instead ?

Comment: Angular creates sourcemap for template. Just click on the line with error and you will see where is error in your template. I mean line with `<@ng:///AppModule/UploadScriptFormComponent.ngfactory.js:346:9` text

Comment: It's not working (at least in firefox), is it supposed to show an actual line inside my source files ? Clicking the stack trace just opens the side panel where I can explore its properties but that's it